# How to change Postgresql query according to the request in Golang?

Tags: postgresql, go

Let's say I have this query and I'm using Golang to communicate

```
SELECT
    u."id",
    u."name",
    u.accreditation 
FROM
    universities u 
WHERE
    u.accreditation ILIKE ANY ( $1 ) 
    OR NOT u.accreditation ILIKE ANY ( '{A, B, C}' ) ;
```

The case is I want to make the query `OR NOT u.accreditation ILIKE ANY ( '{A, B, C}' )` as a variable $2 like this

```
SELECT
    u."id",
    u."name",
    u.accreditation 
FROM
    universities u 
WHERE
    u.accreditation ILIKE ANY ( $1 ) 
    $2 ;
```

- If $1 contains "O" then $2 is `OR NOT u.accreditation ILIKE ANY ( '{A, B, C}' )`.
- If $1 does not contains "O" then $2 is   <= empty string.

But it can't be done. What should I do?

Comment: Parameter placeholders are for **values** *only*. Conditional statements like `OR NOT some_column ILIKE ...` are not values. They are statements. If you need to execute different SQL queries then you need to write or generate two different SQL queries.

Comment: ow. any other work around to get something like that?

Comment: Build the query using [fmt.Sprintf](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf) or [strings.Builder](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder).

Comment: Building on @Adrian's suggestion, the [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) package requires a few more lines but can be very readable.